# Subset 3D matrix using polygon coordinates

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I'm working on some bioacoustical analysis and got stuck with an issue that I believe it can be worked out mathematically. I'll use an sound sample from `seewave`package:

`library(seewave)`
`library(tuneR)`

```
data(tico)
```

By storing a spectrogram (i.e. graphic representation of the sound wave `tico`) in an R object, we can now deal with the wave file computationally.

```
s <- spectro(tico, plot=F)
class(s)
>[1] "list"

length(s)
>[1] 3
```

The object created `s` consists in two numerical vectors `x = s$time`, `y = s$freq` representing the X and Y axis, respectively, and a matrix `z = s$amp` of amplitude values with the same dimensions of x and y. Z is a virtually a 3D matrix that can be plotted using `persp3D` (`plot3D`), `plot_ly` (`plotly`) or `plot3d` (`rgl`). Alternatively, the wave file can be plotted in 3D using `seewave` if one wishes to visualize it as an interative `rgl` plot.

```
spectro3D(tico)
```

That being said, the analysis I'm conducting aims to calculate contours of relative amplitude:

```
con <- contourLines(x=s$time, y=s$freq, z=t(s$amp), levels=seq(-25, -25, 1))
```

Select the longest contour:

```
n.con <- numeric(length(con))
for(i in 1:length(con)) n.con[i] <- length(con[[i]]$x)
n.max <- which.max(n.con)
con.max <- con[[n.max]]
```

And then plot the selected contour against the spectrogram of `tico`:

```
spectro(tico, grid=F, osc=F, scale=F)
polygon(x=con.max$x, y=con.max$y, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Now it comes the tricky part. I must find a way to "subset" the matrix of amplitude values `s$amp` using the coordinates of the longest contour `con.max`. What I aim to achieve is a new matrix containing only the amplitude values inside the polygon. The remaining parts of the spectrogram should then appear as blank spaces.

One approach I though it could work would be to create a loop that replaces every value outside the polygon for a given amplitude value (e.g. -25 dB). I once did an similar approach to remove the values below -30 dB and it worked out perfectly:

```
for(i in 1:length(s$amp)){if(s$amp[i] == -Inf |s$amp[i] <= -30)
{s$amp[i] <- -30}}
```

Another though would be to create a new matrix with the same dimensions of `s$amp`, subset `s$amp` using the coordinates of the contour, then replace the  subset on the new matrix. Roughly:

```
mt <- matrix(-30, nrow=nrow(s$amp), ncol = ncol(s$amp))
sb <- s$amp[con.max$y, con.max$x]
new.mt <- c(mt, sb)
s$amp <- new.mt
```

I'll appreciate any help.